# Bash String Manipulation and Assignment

Tags: bash, shell, variable, string, assignment

How can I manipulate a string and then assign it to a variable?

This string manipulation works as I want:

```
echo ${dir:2:5} | sed 's/[.]$//';
```

but:

```
var x = ${dir:2:5} | sed 's/[.]$//';
```

and

```
x = ${dir:2:5} | sed 's/[.]$//';
```

and

```
x = $(${dir:2:5} | sed 's/[.]$//');
```

all produce errors similar to:

```
script.sh: line 2: mystring: command not found
script.sh: line 2: x: command not found
script.sh: line 2: var: command not found
```

My intention is to use this variable in an `mv` command.

```
mv /var/$x/test/$x.mp4 /home/me/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
x=$(echo "${dir:2:5}" | sed 's/\.$//')
```

1. You have to omit the spaces in when you declare a variable (`x=value`)
2. `$dir` is a variable. To print the output of your command you would use `echo "${dir:2:5}" | sed 's/\.$//'` in the terminal. To save the value in variable `x`, you replace the value with your command using command substitution `$( )`

Comment: Thanks, this is functioning as I expected. The explanation also helps.

Answer (score 2):

Supplement to [*Freddy*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515469/165517); the `sed` pipe could also be replaced with a [`bash` string substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script).  Example:

```
x=abcd.efghijk ; y="${x:2:5}" ; echo "$y"  "${y/.}"
```

Output:

```
cd.ef cdef
```